# I am trying to integrate firebase in my react native app in expo-cli

Tags: firebase, react-native

After importing the package, I got an error that says

> Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hp\react-firebase\node_modules\firebase\dist\index.cjs.js'

I also imported it this way and used it this way

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyBBbX7UGC4Pkq4gHu2fO_zDGruliF1EJC8",
  authDomain: "react-firebase-881ec.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://react-firebase-881ec.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "react-firebase-881ec",
  storageBucket: "react-firebase-881ec.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "721639090613",
  appId: "1:721639090613:web:a70bfb1a95e72aaf8451fc",
  measurementId: "G-82VLJWB7SR"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

import {Container, Header, Item, Input, Content, Form, Label, Button} from 'native-base'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Form>
          <Item>
            <Label>Email</Label>
            <Input 
            autoCorrect={false}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            />
          </Item>
        </Form>
      </Container>
     );
  }
}
```

Hope anybody can help

Answer (score 1):

Try the below ones:

1. `npm rebuild node-sass`
2. Or else delete `node_modules` folder and re-run `npm install`
3. Or else crate the empty file inside the node_modules at the path where the file is missing error is shown.

   `touch C:\Users\hp\react-firebase\node_modules\firebase\dist\index.cjs.js`